# Take 1 inside GroupBy in Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have a query which returns a number of records.

For Example:

- Date is 26-Feb then 10 records are returned for this date.
- Date is 27-Feb then 15 records are returned for this date.

[Click to See Records](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B20qWQW8lE2ddGxjVmdfdjVZY0E/edit?usp=sharing)

I used the following query:

```
 var sData = vehicle.GsmDeviceLogs
                    .Where(gs => gs.Speed > zeroSpeed && !gs.DigitalInputLevel1)
                    .OrderBy(gs => gs.DateTimeOfLog)
                    .ToList();
```

Now, I just want to fetch the first record for each date. i.e.

- Date is 26-Feb - 1 Record.
- Date is 27-Feb - 1 Record.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You gave the answer in your question itself, group by and then select the first.
Technically you would translate it to linq as the following:

```
var sData = vehicle.GsmDeviceLogs
              .Where(gs => gs.Speed > zeroSpeed && !gs.DigitalInputLevel1)
              .OrderBy(gs => gs.DateTimeOfLog)
              .GroupBy(gs => gs.DateTimeOfLog)
              .Select(gs => gs.First())
              .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should group the records by `DateTimeOfLog.Date` (which returns a `DateTime` containing only the date part), and then get the first one of each group through a `Select`, like so:

```
var data = logs.Where( ... )
               .GroupBy( l => l.DateTimeOfLog.Date )
               .Select( g => new { Date = g.Key, Log = g.First() } );
```

(I used an anonymous type; you may prefer to use tuples depending on how you use that data)